# dynamically drawing polylines on googlemaps using php/mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xml, google-maps

I am new to the googlemaps API. I have written a small app for my mobile phone that periodically updates its location to an SQL databse.

I would like to display this information on a googlemap in my browser. Ideally i'd like to then poll the database periodically and if any new co-ords have arrived, add them to the line.

Best way of describing it is [this](http://www.instamapper.com/fe?page=demo).

In a quest to get to there, i've started on the documents on google and been modifying them to try and acheive what I want. It doesn't work - and i don't know enough to know why. I would love some advice as to why, and any pointers towards my ultimate goal would be very much welcomed.
    
    
      
       
       Google Maps AJAX + MySQL/PHP Example

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[

function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(47.614495, -122.341861), 13);

    GDownloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
      var xml = GXml.parse(data);
      var line = [];
      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("points");
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            var point = points.item(i);
            var lat  = point.getAttribute("lat");
            var lng  = point.getAttribute("lng");

            var latlng = new GLatLng(lat, lng);

       line.push(latlng);
       if (point.firstChild) {
         var station = point.firstChild.nodeValue;
         var marker = createMarker(latlng, station);
         map.addOverlay(marker);
       }
     }

     var polyline = new GPolyline(line, "#ff0000", 3, 1);
     map.addOverlay(polyline);
});
}
//]]>
```

My php file is generating the following XML;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<points>
<point lng="-122.340141" lat="47.608940"/>
<point lng="-122.344391" lat="47.613590"/>
<point lng="-122.356445" lat="47.624561"/>
<point lng="-122.337654" lat="47.606365"/>
<point lng="-122.345673" lat="47.612823"/>
<point lng="-122.340363" lat="47.605961"/>
<point lng="-122.345467" lat="47.613976"/>
<point lng="-122.326584" lat="47.617214"/>
<point lng="-122.342834" lat="47.610126"/>
</points>
```

I have successfully worked through this; http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html before attempting to customise the code.

Any pointers? Where am I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track.

Your php script should accept a timestamp parameter, and should check if new points have been inserted in the database after that timestamp. If yes, it should return a response with the latest entry (or a list of entries after that timestamp, if you want to show a live trail as the vehicle moves).

On the client-side, you may want to initiate an AJAX request to the server-side script, either using normal or [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)#Ajax_with_long_polling), with the timestamp parameter of the last update.

When your AJAX request receives new information from the server, you would simply move your markers on the map. Then initiate a new AJAX request with the updated timestamp paramater.

Pseudocode-ish example using [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
var lastUpdate = '2000/01/01 00:00:00';

function autoUpdate () {
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "phpsqlajax_genxml.php?last_update=" + lastUpdate,
       dataType: 'xml',
       success: function(xmlData) {

          // 1. Check if the xmlData is empty. If not we received 
          //    some fresh data.
          // 2. Update lastUpdate from the xmlData with the timestamp from 
          //    the server. Don't use JavaScript to update the timestamp, 
          //    because the time on the client and on the server will 
          //    never be exactly in sync.
          // 3. Move the markers on Google Map.

          // Relaunch the autoUpdate() function in 5 seconds.
          setTimeout(autoUpdate, 5000);
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have got the above bit of code working now, i had made some careless mistakes with it that i just couldn't see for looking. AJAX is another new to me (not that up on web tbh) but will look into it and try and apply what you've said.