# Google map draw poly line using database details

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps

hai i am doing some works with google map using php!

**i want to know how to draw polyline in google map using database lon and lan details **

Comment: Hi Thula, welcome to SO. This is a programming related Q&A forum, so please show some code. What have you tried so far and into which problems did you run?

Answer (score 0):

you can draw polyline in javascript like this way

this is for google map v2

```
var polyline = new GPolyline([
  new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
  new GLatLng(37.4519, -122.1519)
], "#ff0000", 10);
map.addOverlay(polyline);
```

for more detail see [this link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Polylines_Overview)

see php is server side programming language and this can be doing in javascript you have to pass the data to the javascript. you need to send the request to the server for getting the response in javascript and this can be done many way like page load time you fetch the data and pass into the javascript any in any event

Comment: no i know draw poly line but the matter is how to get database details and draw it

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439585/dynamically-drawing-polylines-on-googlemaps-using-php-mysql