# SQL to google map points

Tags: mysql, sql, google-maps

I have a database where latitude and longitude co-ordinates are uploaded every minute or so.

I want to display all the points with a connecting line on a map.
I have no idea where I would start so some direction would be really useful.
I've been able to output the coordinates however I don't know how to display google maps and place markers with a connected line.

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
print($row['PointLat'] . " " . $row['PointLon'] . "/");
    }
    ?>
```

It also needs to be in way that it can handle a large number of coordinates. 
It could potentially be querying 1000s from that table.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very similar question was asked here:

[dynamically drawing polylines on googlemaps using php/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439585/dynamically-drawing-polylines-on-googlemaps-using-php-mysql)

Hope it is useful.

Edit:
- This question includes how to draw a line - That is done using polylines and overlays - see right at the bottom of the code where it says:

```
var polyline = new GPolyline(line, "#ff0000", 3, 1);
 map.addOverlay(polyline);
```

Comment: No problem - if it answers your query grateful if you could accept the answer. Best of luck.